# Rails Custom Route Redirecting to Show

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a custom route `make_winner_pick` but every time I click the link to follow the path the controller defaults to the `show` action. I can't understand what I'm doing wrong and it's driving me nuts

> **routes.rb**

```
resources :league_members

get "league_members/make_winner_pick" => "league_members#make_winner_pick", :as => :make_winner_pick
```

> **Where the path is called**

```
<%= link_to 'Join League', make_winner_pick_path(league: league.id), method: :get %>
```

> **The console**

```
    Started GET "/league_members/make_winner_pick?league=3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-29 01:33:56 +0100
    Processing by LeagueMembersController#show as HTML
      Parameters: {"league"=>"3", "id"=>"make_winner_pick"}
      User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 2  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
      LeagueMember Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "league_members".* FROM "league_members"  WHERE "league_members"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "league_members"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
    Completed 404 Not Found in 5ms

    ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find LeagueMember with 'id'=make_winner_pick):
      app/controllers/league_members_controller.rb:68:in `set_league_member'
```

Can anyone tell me why my custom route is not being fired and Rails is defaulting to the `#show` action? For some reason it appears to be looking for a `league_member` with an id of `make_winner_pick`

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try nest your route within the resource:

```
resources :league_members do
  collection do
    get "make_winner_pick" => "league_members#make_winner_pick", :as => :make_winner_pick
  end
end
```

Because rails recognized your route `make_winner_pick` as an `id`.

Comment: Thanks a million for that. Works perfectly.

Comment: Note: This method changes your specified helper by appending the collection-name to what you specify with ":as => my_route_helper" .  Putting your custom route before the "resources" line in the route file, ensures your route will be found first, before the Rails 'show' route can get to it, and preserves the helper name as you specify it.

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

`<%= link_to 'Join League', league_members_make_winner_pick_path(league: league.id), method: :get %>`

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work. Get `undefined local variable or method league_members_make_winner_pick_path' for #<#<Class:........`. nayiaw's solution below works perfectly

Comment: Apologies, I actually needed `make_winner_pick_league_members_path` when I made the adjustments nayiaw suggested. Not quite sure why as I thought explicitly naming the path `:as => :make_winner_pick` meant I could just use `make_winner_pick_path`. But for whatever reason I can't (because it's nested possibly?)