# Custom route redirect to wrong action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following in my routes file:

```
  resources :exercises, shallow: true do
    resources :questions do
      resources :test_cases do
        member do
          post :run, to: 'test_cases#run'
        end
      end
    end
  end

  get 'test_cases/test', to: 'test_cases#test'
```

My problem is with the `test` route, outside the resources. Checking the available routes I have what I want:

```
test_cases_test GET    /test_cases/test(.:format)                       test_cases#test
```

However, if I call `test_cases_test_url` from a view I'm redirected to `test_cases#show`, no `test_cases#test` how it should be. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32281586/rails-custom-route-redirecting-to-show) is about the same problem in a different situation. I don't want to follow the accepted answer because if I put `get 'test', to: 'test_cases#test'` inside my `resources :test_cases` and outside `member` block I'll got the question_id in my route, and inside `member` block the test_case_id. I don't need these ids.

I have any option to get my desired route(`test_cases/test`) working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you're matching on the test_cases#show method because it has the same pattern as the `test_cases/test` url and it comes before.  Just move the `test_cases/test` get route to the top of your routes file

```
get 'test_cases/test', to: 'test_cases#test'

resources :exercises, shallow: true do
  resources :questions do
    resources :test_cases do
      member do
        post :run, to: 'test_cases#run'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Another way, which I'd recommended

```
resources :exercises, shallow: true do
  resources :questions do
    resources :test_cases do
      member do
        post :run
        get :test
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Excelent, @Swards. It worked! These are my `test` and `show` routes:`test_cases_test GET    /test_cases/test(.:format)` and `test_case GET    /test_cases/:id(.:format)`. Only to understand (it may seem like a silly question, but this routes issues confuse me sometimes): looking these routes, when you say that they have the same pattern, what exacltly is "the same" here?

Comment: If you do a `rake routes` in console you can see the patterns that match.  For the test_case path, the :id is a parameter and can be anything.  So, in this case "GET /test_case/<anything>" will got to `test_cases#show` and "GET /test_case/test" will go to `test_case#test`.  The more restrictive routes should be first in the routes file.  Routes are used for two main things - generating url strings and matching url requests to controller#actions.  It matches in order of the routes file.  It's the matching part that was catching you, the generating URL was working as expected.

Comment: @rwehresmann - added another option to the answer, probably better for your situation

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! About the other option, I prefer not to add my `test` route in the member block. If I do this, I add `test_case_id` to my route, and in my particular case I do not use this id for anything.